# New Responses of Multiple Google Forms into one single tab of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have multiple google forms and I want to be notified when there are new responses. Some forms do not get daily new responses so I would like to save my time instead of checking each response spreadsheet daily (each form has their own spreadsheet and I cannot send all responses to one spreadsheet).

I thought of having one new spreadsheet (only one tab) where the tab will be updated each time there is a new response and will also indicate from which form or response sheet it was derived from.

I tried import range but I do not know how to do it with multiple forms or different spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

You have several Google Forms, each linked to a Google Spreadsheet (each Form is linked to separate spreadsheet). You want to receive a notification when a submission is received rather than checking each spreadsheet.

The following answer:

- interrogates the respective linked spreadsheets
- determines whether there have been any new submissions, and
- sends a **single** email notification showing the status for all Forms.

**To-Do**

- create/use a spreadsheet to manage the notifications
- create sheet `Forms` (refer snapshot below)

  - enter headers per snapshot
- for each form enter the following

  - Form name
  - ID of the linked spreadsheet
  - sheet name on the linked spreadsheet
- regarding `# received last query`,

  - this is updated by the script, but for start values

    - EITHER: leave this blank (in which case, an initial email will reference all submissions)
    - OR: enter the number of submissions at the time of creating the script.
- Update the `recipient` email address in the script.
- create an installable time-driven trigger for the function; chose a frequency to suit.

---

```
function formNotif() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Forms")

  // get the data
  var dataLR = sheet.getLastRow()
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,dataLR,4)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
  var data = dataRange.getValues()

  // email variables
  var subject = "Form notifications"
  var body = "Submissions have been received for:"
  var bodyDetails = ""
  var recipient = "<<INSERT RECIPIENT EMAIL ADDRESS>>"

  // loop through the data
  // set i=1 to avoid headers
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
   
    var sheetID = data[i][1]
    var sheetName = data[i][2]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet id = "+sheetID)
    var formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName(sheetName)
    var lastEnquiry = data[i][3]
    if (lastEnquiry == ""){
      // cell is blank, assign zero
      lastEnquiry = 0
    }
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: last enquiry = "+lastEnquiry+ ", type of "+(typeof lastEnquiry))
    var thisEnquiry = formSheet.getLastRow()-1
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: this enquiry = "+thisEnquiry+ ", type of "+(typeof thisEnquiry))
    var newSubmissions = thisEnquiry-lastEnquiry
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: New submissions = "+newSubmissions+ ", type of "+(typeof newSubmissions))
    var formName =data[i][0] 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: form name: "+formName)
    if (newSubmissions != 0){
      // add new submissions to body
      // Logger.log("DEBUGadd new submissions to body")
      bodyDetails = bodyDetails+"\n"+formName+": "+newSubmissions+" submissions"
    }
    else{
      // no new submissions
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: no new submissions - "+newSubmissions)
      bodyDetails = bodyDetails+"\n"+formName+": No new submissions"
    }

    // update the last equiry value
    data[i][3] = thisEnquiry

    //Logger.log("DEBUG: body details: "+bodyDetails)
  } // end of the loop

  // Logger.log(body+bodyDetails) // DEBUG

  // send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body+bodyDetails, {name: 'Form Submission Script'})

  //update the data range
  dataRange.setValues(data)
}
```

---

**SAMPLE: Forms sheet**

[image: forms]

---

**SAMPLE: Email with Notifications**

[image: all]

---

**SAMPLE: Email with SOME Notifications**
[image: some]

---

**SAMPLE: Email with NO Notifications**

[image: none]